# What is the difference between default import and alias import in ES6?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, import

My question is about what's the difference between these two kinds of import.

`import abc from ./utilities/fibo`
and
`import * as abc from ./utilities/fibo`

I thought they were almost same, but it turns out something is out of my expectation.

Although I think the problem is platform agnostic, this is written in react native. Expo version 27.1.

Two simple js file:

fibo.js:

```
export default "string";
```

app.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import abc from './utilities/fibonacci';

debugger // set break point here

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Text>{abc}</Text>
    );
  }
}
```

You can see that I have set break point in app.js.
When I run the code, it stops at the break point.
When I inspect `abc` then, a reference error told me that

> abc is not defined

But this totally works in `<Text>{abc}</Text>` and it renders correctly.

If I use an alias for the imported module:

app.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import * as abc from './utilities/fibonacci';

debugger // set break point here

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Text>{abc}</Text>
    );
  }
}
```

Run code again, break point meets me.
Inspection of `abc` tells me that it is already defined as an object with a property named as 'default' whose value is 'string'.

And the difference doesn't just stop here.
Resume to run the code, error jumps out:

> Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {default}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

I have to change `<Text>{abc}</Text>` to `<Text>{abc.default}</Text>` to make things happen.

So, what is difference between them? And why?

Comment: You should use `import {abc} from './utilities/fibonacci';`

Comment: i hope all these link will surely help you, if you have any other doubt let me know, i will reopen your ques :)

Comment: you have to export a variable, like this `export default const fibo = "string";`